# Regex to find 4th value inside bracket

Tags: regex

How i can read 4th Value(inside "" i.e "vV0...." using Regex in below condition ?

I am updating a bit this part - Is it possible to first find Word "LaunchFileUploader" and then select the 4th Value, if there are multiple instance of LaunchFileUploader in the file just select 4th Value of first word found ? Attaching screenshot of file where this needs to be searched (In the file word is "LaunchFileUploader")

[image]

I tried this but it gives as - I need 4th value (Group 1 is giving me third value)

```
\bLaunchFileUploader\b(\:?.*?,){3}.*?\)

Match 1
Full match  11030-11428 LaunchFileUploader("ERM-1BLX3D04R10-0001", 1662, "2ecbb644-34fa-4919-9809-a5ff47594c2d", "8dZOPyHKBK...

Group 1.    n/a  "2ecbb644-34fa-4919-9809-a5ff47594c2d",
```

I am still looking for solution for this. Any help is aprreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Here are some pointers: they're inside parenthesis and they are delimited by commas (though you'd have to account for the comments).

Comment: Comments are just for refrence and exlaning the problem, they dont exist in reality

Comment: which language are you using?  there are differences for patterns in each.  also, what's your exact expected output/match?  (with or without quotes)

Comment: Without quote , it is in Java

Comment: How about: `\bLaunchFileUploader\((?:[^,]*,){3}([^,)]+)`?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what's available to you to use, there's a couple of ways to do it.

Either way, this would work better if there were no new lines in the string, just plain `("value1","value2","value3","value4")` etc. It'll still work, but you may need to clean up some new lines from the resulting string.

The easy way - use code for the hard part. Grab the inner string with:

```
(?<=\().*?(?=\))
```

This will get everything that's between the 2 parentheses (using positive lookarounds). In code, you could then split/explode this string on `,` and take the 4th item.

If you want to do it all in regex, you could use something along the lines of:

```
(?<=\()(?:.*?,){3}(.*?)(?=\))
```

This would a) match the entire contents of the parentheses and b) capture the 4th option in a capture group. To go even deeper:

```
(?<=\()(?:.*?,){3}\"(.*?)\"(?=\))
```

would capture the contents of the `""` quotation marks only.

Some tools don't allow you to use lookarounds, if this is the case let me know and I'll see what other ways there are around it.

**EDIT** Ran this in JS console on browser. This absolutely does work.

[image: console]

**EDIT 2** I see you've updated your question with the text you're actually searching in. This pattern will include the space and the new line character as per the copy/paste of the above text.

```
(?<=\(\")(?:.*?,\s?\n?){3}\"(.*?)\"(?=\))
```

See my second image for the test in console

[image: console 2]

Comment: I used https://regexr.com/ to test and none of the above worked, it is selecting everything (all values), i need only 4th value without quotes

Comment: @user662285 yes if you hover over the selected text in the last pattern in my answer, you'll see the capture group contains just that.

Comment: @user662285 regex101.com is a much better tool to use, shows matches more clearly.

Comment: @user662285 it sure does. Check my updated answer, you'll see I tested it in console.

Comment: Updated a bit, see if you can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193539/discussion-between-user662285-and-jamie-fenrir-digital-ltd).

Answer (score 1):

This works for python and PHP:
`(?<=\")(.*)(?:\"\);)\Z`
[Demo for Python and PHP](https://regex101.com/r/pFW5fT/1)

For Java, replace `\Z` with `$` as follows:
`(?:")(.*)(?:\"\);)$`
[Demo for JavaScript](https://regex101.com/r/pFW5fT/2)

**NOTE**: Be sure to look the ***captured group*** and not the *matched group*.

**UPDATE**:
Try this for your updated request:
`"(.*)"(?:[\\);\] \/>}]*)$`
[Demo for updated input string](https://regex101.com/r/pFW5fT/4)

*all the above regex patterns assume there is a line break after each comma*

Auto-generated Java Code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "\"(.*)\"(?:[\\\\);\\] \\/>\\}]*)$";
final String string = "\n"
     + "}$(document).ready( function(){ PathUploader\n"
     + "    (\"ERM-1BLX3D04R10-0001\", \n"
     + "    1662, \n"
     + "    \"1bff5c85-7a52-4cc5-86ef-a4ccbf14c5d5\", \n"
     + "\"vV0mX3VadCSPnN8FsAO7%2fysNbP5b3SnaWWHQETFy7ORSoz9QUQUwK7jqvCEr%2f8UnHkNNVLkJedu5l%2bA%2bne%2fD%2b2F5EWVlGox95BYDhl6EEkVAVFmMlRThh1sPzPU5LLylSsR9T7TAODjtaJ2wslruS5nW1A7%2fnLB%2bljZaQhaT9vZLcFkDqLjouf9vu08K9Gmiu6neRVSaISP3cEVAmSz5kxxhV2oiEF9Y0i6Y5%2f5ASaRiW21w3054SmRF0rq3IwZzBvLx0%2fAk1m6B0gs3841b%2fw%3d%3d\"); } );//]]>";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I used regexr.com to test and it did not worked , it is selecting everything (all values), i need only 4th value without quotes

Comment: It works now for Javascript, but it selects "); also in the end, i just want the 4th value without quotes

Comment: it selects it but does NOT capture `");` as noted above.  all you need is to use the captured group.

Comment: Sorry to bother you , i just updated my question can you help me finding the value

Comment: How to check captured group ?

Comment: see auto-generated java code above.  see if you can figure out how to get the captured group.  please don't ask to explain - I am not java dev.

Comment: also, you could check the captured group in the demo link above: it is under "match information" on right side of the screen.

Comment: Updated a bit, see if you can help